# Вывести из массива объектов определенное свойство каждого объекта

Tags: javascript, массивы, объекты

Имеется массив обьектов:

```
[
    {
        id: 1,
        title: 'iPhone 9',
        description: 'An apple mobile which is nothing like apple',
        price: 549,
        discountPercentage: 12.96,
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        title: 'iPhone X',
        description:
            'SIM-Free, Model A19211 6.5-inch Super Retina HD di…lay with OLED technology A12 Bionic chip with ...',
        price: 899,
        discountPercentage: 17.94,
    },
    {
        id: 3,
        title: 'Samsung Universe 9',
        description:
            "Samsung's new variant which goes beyond Galaxy to the Universe",
        price: 1249,
        discountPercentage: 15.46,
    },
    {
        id: 4,
        title: 'OPPOF19',
        description: 'OPPO F19 is officially announced on April 2021.',
        price: 280,
        discountPercentage: 17.91,
    },
    {
        id: 5,
        title: 'Huawei P30',
        description:
            'Huawei’s re-badged P30 Pro New Edition was officia…ny and now the device has made its way to the UK.',
        price: 499,
        discountPercentage: 10.58,
    },
    {
        id: 6,
        title: 'MacBook Pro',
        description:
            'MacBook Pro 2021 with mini-LED display may launch between September, November',
        price: 1749,
        discountPercentage: 11.02,
    },
];
```

Каким способом можно вывести из этого массива объектов конкретно нужное мне свойства вида:

```
[ {id: 1}, {id: 2}, {id: 3} // и т.д.]
```

Comment: Если прочитать чуть-чуть книжечку для новичков, то там всегда есть раздел ЦИКЛЫ и МАССИВЫ. Вы их знаете?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Прочитайте про массивы, и их методы.
И тогда такие банальные вопросы отпадут

```js
const data = [
    {
        id: 1,
        title: 'iPhone 9',
        description: 'An apple mobile which is nothing like apple',
        price: 549,
        discountPercentage: 12.96,
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        title: 'iPhone X',
        description:
            'SIM-Free, Model A19211 6.5-inch Super Retina HD di…lay with OLED technology A12 Bionic chip with ...',
        price: 899,
        discountPercentage: 17.94,
    },
    {
        id: 3,
        title: 'Samsung Universe 9',
        description:
            "Samsung's new variant which goes beyond Galaxy to the Universe",
        price: 1249,
        discountPercentage: 15.46,
    },
    {
        id: 4,
        title: 'OPPOF19',
        description: 'OPPO F19 is officially announced on April 2021.',
        price: 280,
        discountPercentage: 17.91,
    },
    {
        id: 5,
        title: 'Huawei P30',
        description:
            'Huawei’s re-badged P30 Pro New Edition was officia…ny and now the device has made its way to the UK.',
        price: 499,
        discountPercentage: 10.58,
    },
    {
        id: 6,
        title: 'MacBook Pro',
        description:
            'MacBook Pro 2021 with mini-LED display may launch between September, November',
        price: 1749,
        discountPercentage: 11.02,
    },
];

function getIdList(arr) {
  return arr.map((el) => ({id: el.id}))
}

const idList = getIdList(data)
console.log(idList)
```